# Allow traffic from certain machines - Google Cloud Armor

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-armor

I have a Google Cloud Run services and i would need to allow traffic from certain machine only.
I use Google cloud armor to allow IPs to access the Cloud Run service.
I have problem in adding dynamic IPs of certain machine as it keeps changing. I also searched on adding mac address to allow, but Cloud armor does not have that feature.

Answer (score 3):

1. You cannot use MAC addresses for the Internet. The service (Cloud Armor) will never see the client's MAC address, only the MAC address of the last router (which would be a Google router). Google Cloud VPCs do not expose layer 2 information.
2. Cloud Run is a public service with a public URL. Restricting traffic based upon IP address is not supported by Cloud Run. You can put an HTTP Load Balancer and Cloud Armor in front, but that would not prevent traffic that goes directly to the service.

There are much better techniques to control access to public services. Google Cloud implements authorization using OAuth via Identity Aware Proxy (IAP). That is the correct method to use. Given that your clients have changing IP addresses, that is your best solution.

If I needed access control based upon IP address, I would run my service on Compute Engine using either Container Optimized OS, Docker or just natively using Apache/Nginx. You can dynamically update VPC firewall rules as the client's IP address changes with custom code.